# Make web api controller read content instead of using lazystreamcontent

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following method in a web API controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Logs")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddLogsAsync([FromBody] List<Log> logList)
{
    if (logList.Count > 0)
    {
        using (var database = new DatabaseContextHandler())
        {
            await database.AddLogsAsync(logList);
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

It usually works, until I tried to send a 6.7 MB JSON `logList` to it and got a `NullReferenceException` on `(logList.Count > 0)`, which obviously means `logList` was `null`. After confirming my JSON was properly formatted I re-sended the same JSON, this time while debugging the API, and saw that not only `logList` was `null`, but `Request.Content` was showing up as `LazyStreamContent`, which I assume is how the controller handles somewhat large content bodies.

I could call `ReadAsStringAsync()`, then deserialize it inside the method but that means I'd have to make this change to every controller to avoid having this issue somewhere else later.

So my question is, is there some way of preventing the controller to use `LazyStreamContent`? Make it always read the request fully before entering the method? I tried digging through the documentation but couldn't find any configuration that seemed to do something like this.

Comment: Have you looked into creating an `ActionFilter` and overriding `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` and then add to the `GlobalFilters` so it runs across the entire application?

Comment: Find a solution?

Comment: @Roger this probably wouldn't help you 3 months later, but in case someone else somehow finds his way here through google, the issue here had something to with some default limit asp.net imposes on the size of the json body of incoming requests. Changing the limit it on the web.config file solved the issue for me and the object was desserialized normally before reaching the controller code. I don't remember what exactly I had to add on web.config to change this limit though